# Add custom bindTooltip class

Tags: css, class, leaflet, tooltip

I am trying to add custom class to my bindTooltip but the new class do not show up. My method based on [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/212820/overriding-leaflet-tooltip-style) question.

My custom popup class is working fine but if I want to overwrite the tooltip class than it is now working.

**My JS code:**

```
 var PopupClass={'className': 'class-popup'}
 var TooltipClass={'className': 'class-tooltip'}

L.marker(
  [46.17319713, 21.34458608],
  {icon: OnlineMarker}
).bindPopup(
  'Test Popup', 
  PopupClass
).bindTooltip(
  'Test Tooltip',
  {direction: 'top', permanent: true, offset: [10,0]}, 
  TooltipClass
).addTo(MyMap)
```

**My CSS code:**

```
/* popup-class*/

.class-popup .leaflet-popup-content-wrapper {
  background:#2980b9;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:10px;
  line-height:10px;
  }

.class-popup .leaflet-popup-content-wrapper a {
  color:#2980b9;
  }
.class-popup .leaflet-popup-tip-container {
  width:40px;
  height:20px;
  }
.class-popup .leaflet-popup-tip {
  background:#2980b9;
  }

/* tooltip-class*/ 

.class-tooltip{
  background: green;
  border: 2px solid cyan
}
.leaflet-tooltip-left.class-tooltip::before {
  border-left-color: cyan;
}
.leaflet-tooltip-right.class-tooltip::before {
  border-right-color: cyan;
}
```

Comment: Sorry is that was just an typo, on my code it is in corrett syntact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 issues:

1. You try to specify your Tooltip class using a 3rd argument of `.bindTooltip`, which does not do anything as per Leaflet doc. Instead, you should merge your `className` key in the 2nd argument (`options`). For that, you can either:

   - write it directly within the `options`
   - [extend](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#util-extend) your TooltipClass with your options: `L.Util.extend(myOptions, TooltipClass)`
   - use the [ES2018 spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) to do the same as the above point.
2. Your `.class-tooltip` selector in CSS is not enough to override the default Leaflet style. Increase your selector specificity, e.g. adding the Leaflet tooltip class: `.leaflet-tooltip.class-tooltip`

```js
var MyMap = L.map('map').setView([46.17319713, 21.34458608], 11);
var PopupClass = {
  'className': 'class-popup'
}
var TooltipClass = {
  'className': 'class-tooltip'
}

L.marker([46.17319713, 21.34458608])
  .bindPopup('Test Popup', PopupClass)
  .bindTooltip('Test Tooltip', {
    direction: 'top',
    permanent: true,
    offset: [10, 0],
    //'className': 'class-tooltip'
    ...TooltipClass // using spread operator (ES2018)
  }, TooltipClass) // 3rd argument does not do anything
  .addTo(MyMap);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(MyMap);
```

```css
/* popup-class*/

.class-popup .leaflet-popup-content-wrapper {
  background: #2980b9;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 10px;
}

.class-popup .leaflet-popup-content-wrapper a {
  color: #2980b9;
}

.class-popup .leaflet-popup-tip-container {
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
}

.class-popup .leaflet-popup-tip {
  background: #2980b9;
}


/* tooltip-class*/

.leaflet-tooltip.class-tooltip {
  background: green;
  border: 2px solid cyan
}

.leaflet-tooltip-left.class-tooltip::before {
  border-left-color: cyan;
}

.leaflet-tooltip-right.class-tooltip::before {
  border-right-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet-src.js" integrity="sha512-IkGU/uDhB9u9F8k+2OsA6XXoowIhOuQL1NTgNZHY1nkURnqEGlDZq3GsfmdJdKFe1k1zOc6YU2K7qY+hF9AodA==" crossorigin=""></script>

<div id="map" style="height: 180px"></div>
```

Comment: Your answer working perfectly, it was very useful I think.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! :-)